# Docker stack/service doesn't work, how to debug?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am making stack for docker-swarm.

This is my stack for django and nginx.

I deploy this but it never start.

```
ID                  NAME                    MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                 PORTS
n9j49jx667x5        django_nginx    replicated          0/1                 nginx:1.13                            *:8000->8000/tcp
7h3sbmmgwbvn        django_python   replicated          0/1                 registry:5000/mydjango:latest   *:8082->8082/tcp
dkzk9z3rdtzm        phpmyadmin_phpmyadmin   global              1/1                 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest          *:8009->80/tcp
kf6xisbvqdqv        visualizer_app          global              1/1                 dockersamples/visualizer:latest       *:9009->8080/tcp
```

Now I want to check why this stack dosen't work.

but how can I check the log or some clue??

If service is once works, I can check like

```
docker container exec -it manager docker service logs -f visualizer_app
```

But how can I investigate why stack/service doesn't work...??

```
version: '3'
services:
  python:
    image: registry:5000/mydjango:latest
    command: uwsgi --socket :8001 --module jrtweet.wsgi --py-autoreload 1 --logto /tmp/mylog.log
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/code
      - ./src/static:/static
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/uwsgi_params:/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
      - ./static:/static
    depends_on:
      - python
```

even I tried the most simple setting, but it doesn't work and I don't even know how to debug.....

---

I found out the reason why it dosen't work try and error.

I commented out `#volumes` it works, but this must be a another question...

I still want to know the debug of service launch.....

---

THanks to taleodor I can found the log `service ps`

```
docker container exec -it man docker service ps django_python


mbx47zczllwm        django_python.1       registry:5000/myprog/djangosrc:latest   6b0938c9c5fb        Ready               Rejected less than a second ago   "invalid mount config for type…"   
xgpet2jwwocq         \_ django_python.1   registry:5000/myprog/djangosrc:latest   6b0938c9c5fb        Shutdown            Rejected less than a second ago   "invalid mount config for type…"   
zl1z7a0qx330         \_ django_python.1   registry:5000/myprog/djangosrc:latest   6b0938c9c5fb        Shutdown            Rejected 38 seconds ago           "invalid mount config for type…"   
zewlsc76zluy         \_ django_python.1   registry:5000/myprog/djangosrc:latest   6b0938c9c5fb        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago       "invalid mount config for type…"   
zytucyx6unsg         \_ django_python.1   registry:5000/myprog/djangosrc:latest   6b0938c9c5fb        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago       "invalid mount config for type…"   
zqjdobhkti47         \_ django_python.1   registry:5000/myprog/djangosrc:latest   6b0938c9c5fb        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago       "invalid mount config for type…"   
zxe18cc554ev         \_ django_python.1   registry:5000/myprog/djangosrc:latest   6b0938c9c5fb        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago       "invalid mount config for type…"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do *docker service ps*, i.e.:

   *docker service ps django_nginx*
2. This will give you clues about attempts to start server and possible errors. If the error is clear enough, stop there.
3. If the error is not clear - and containers were started but exited quickly, locate those containers via *docker ps* and get their logs via

   *docker logs container_id*

Comment: Thank you very much!! 1)`docker container exec -it man docker service ps django_python ` it shows "invalid mount config for type…" this is very usuful information.

Comment: As for 3, I check the node and service id by `service ps` and then try `docker container exec -it 6b0938c9c5fb docker logs mbx47zczllwm` but it returns `Error: No such container: mbx47zczllwm`, maybe this is service id. is it possible to get the container id?? container is already shutdowned..

Comment: You can do `docker ps -a` to get all containers, including stopped ones, and then grep by name. Note that they are destroyed pretty quickly, but if you do it fast - right after you get a failure on swarm, you may be able to locate most recent one. Unfortunately, I didn't find a better native way to hold on to those containers.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduling level errors, like "image not found", "no suitable node for placement constraint" or "volume plugin errors" can be identified like this:
`docker service ps django_python --no-trunc`

`--no-trunc` will prevent the error message to be cut off.

Swarm deployments require bind-mounts (the type you try to use) to use absolute paths.

Lets assume your docker-compose.yml is located in /home/user/docker-compose.yml and you want to use the hostpath /home/user/test as "volume source". Then you actualy need to use the absolute path /home/user/tests and not the relative path ./test, like you did in your examples.